# How to find out why a Clojure agent got into invalid state

Tags: clojure, agent

Clojure allows the use of `set-validator!` to check whether the new state of an agent is valid according to some rule. My validator catches a situation when for some reason the agent's values is set to `nil`. However, I cannot figure out how can that happen -- is there some way of pinpointing the action that tried to set the invalid state?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Why not have your validator raise an exception, or log with a stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately, validators seem to have no idea the origin of the action that resulted in an invalid state. The action is put in the queue of the agent. I wonder whether some metadata could be attached to the action that contains the stack trace - it could be helpful during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

agents also work with [watches](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/add-watch), so it is quite reasonable to add a watcher to an agent that logs all the state transitions, this way when things go wrong, you can use this log to replay the transitions that lead to the failure (and hopefully thence to the problem)

```
user> (def x (agent 0))
#'user/x
user> (def states (atom []))
#'user/states
user> (add-watch x :state-logger (fn [& change] (swap! states conj change)))
#<Agent@1dff7647: 0>
user> (send x inc)
#<Agent@1dff7647: 0>
user> (send x dec)
#<Agent@1dff7647: 0>
user> (send x inc)
#<Agent@1dff7647: 1>
user> @states
[(:state-logger #<Agent@1dff7647: 1> 0 1) 
 (:state-logger #<Agent@1dff7647: 1> 1 0) 
 (:state-logger #<Agent@1dff7647: 1> 0 1)]
```

It may be wise to put a `(take 200 ...)` into the watcher so you only keep a reasonable amount of state (or use a ringbuffer)

Comment: Yes, that's a nice way to debug but does not solve the original problem of not knowing the exact code that sent off the action.